# How to animate blocs from left to right with css only?

Tags: css, linux, sass

I'm creating an animation where blocks move from left to right and random top position and their sizes too, partly it worked, but some blocks are very accelerated, can you help me with that?

```css
.slide-bl {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 88, 0, .9);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -40vw;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  // animation: slide-bl 5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) infinite;
}

@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .slide-bl:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation: slide-bl-#{$i} 5s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) infinite;
    animation-delay: calc(random() * -0.2s);
    animation-duration: calc(random() * 50s) + $i;
    left: calc(random() * 16vw + 20px);
    top: calc(random() * 50vh + 80px);
    width: random($limit: 15) + 40px;
    height: random($limit: 15) + 40px;
  }
  @keyframes slide-bl-#{$i} {
    0% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(50vw);
    }
  }
}
```

```php
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    <div class="slide-bl"></div>
@endfor
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hopefully it works. Added `linear` to the timing

```
.slide-bl {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 88, 0, .9);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -40vw;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  animation: slide-bl 10s linear infinite;
}

@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .slide-bl:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay: calc(random() * -0.2s);
    animation-duration: 10s;
    left: calc(random() * 16vw + 20px);
    top: calc(random() * 50vh + 80px);
    width: random($limit: 15) + 40px;
    height: random($limit: 15) + 40px;
  }
}

@keyframes slide-bl {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(50vw);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the speed is working correctly.